# Wordpress, show custom field in orders on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have the latest version of wordpress and woocommerce, and I have try to add some custom field with my order like this :

```
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
{
    if(!empty($_POST['DATE']))
    {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'DATE', sanitize_text_field($_POST['DATE']));
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['HOURS']))
    {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'HOURS', sanitize_text_field($_POST['HOURS']));
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
```

Everything works well, and I can show the diffent field in the admin orders with this function :

```
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order)
{
    ?>
    <p>
        <strong>Date :</strong><br>
        <?=get_post_meta($order->id, 'DATE', true);?>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Date :</strong><br>
        <?=get_post_meta($order->id, 'HOURS', true);?>
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1);
```

But I want to show the custom field like the woocommerce doc (*on the bottom of the screen*) :
[image]

But I don't understand how see this, I have look on the "options" checkbox (on the top right) but all is checked, and I have no option for "custom field", so maybe woocommerce remove this part on the lastest version ?

Thanks

UPDATE :

For me the problem was because of "ACF Pro" plugin who remove that checkbox field, if you want to have both (Woocommerce custom field + ACF Pro custom field) you can just add this code snippet into your `function.php` :

```
add_filter('acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false', 20);
```

Comment: The custom field section on WooCommerce order pages still exist on last WooCommerce version… Now some plugins removes that section like Advanced custom fields plugin and some others…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks for your answer, the problem was like you say about Advanced custom fields plugin, I have a solution in my update post

Answer (score 1):

Check `screen options` on top of the orders page and check if the `custom fields` are checked or not. If custom fields are not checked then it will not show on the page. You can check the screenshots: http://prntscr.com/vug7g8

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I have already check this and the checkbox dosen't appear, the problem was because of ACF pro plugin (see the solution in my update)